# Spring Batch: DelimitedLineTokenizer with line-breaks (newline) in CSV

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

I need to parse an semicolon-separated CSV-File with Spring Batch. Currently I'm using `DelimitedLineTokenizer` within a `DefaultLineMapper`.

The Problem ist, that my CSV rows contains line breaks between quotes. Its kinda multi-line description of every row.

Example:

```
column1;column2;column3;column4
value1;"value2
continuation of value2";column3;column4
```

This leads into the following error:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 4 actual 3
```

So how to tell that Tokenizer to ignore line-breaks `\n` within the quote-escaped columns?

Comment: Your sample isn't quoted…is it in reality?

Comment: Sorry, added quotation.. This is just a mock, the original file has about 100 columns and several thousand rows..

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm assuming it's a semicolon after value1 as well?

Comment: I just added a test to confirm that scenario works and it does.  Are you using a custom `RecordSeperatorPolicy`?  Your configuration would be helpful...

Comment: Argh. The result of endless copy+paste.

Comment: @Micronax did you get a solution?

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/micronax/3e3d41158c58112d5b4df26df110c063